# How to add keyboard shortcuts to Awesome WM

Tags: server, keyboard, awesome

I've installed awesome3 wm on Ubuntu Server 10.04. I managed it to work properly now I could use some keyboard shortcuts to start programs like gmrun, firefox or whatever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, using Awesome version v3.4.15, (you can check version with command line: `awesome -v`)

#### Copying the configuration file to your home dir (file: rc.lua)

If you haven't yet copied the config files from system to your home directory, you can do that with

```
mkdir ~/.config/
mkdir ~/.config/awesome/
cp -r /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua ~/.config/awesome/
```

To copy the default themes as well, so you can change them for user level, do:

```
cp -r /usr/share/awesome/themes/ ~/.config/awesome
```

Then, you can edit `rc.lua` using your favourite editor, for example

```
vim ~/.config/awesome/rc.lua
```

#### Editing `rc.lua`

Find the text in the file

```
-- {{{ Key bindings
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(
```

Below this you can add your custom commands, for example:

```
-- {{{ Key bindings
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(
     -- My Bindings
     awful.key({ }, "F1", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("terminator") end),
```

Here you can change the key which here is `F1`, or program which here is `terminator`.

If you want to add composite keys, put them inside `{` `}`, for example:

```
-- {{{ Key bindings
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(
     -- My Bindings
     awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "F1", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("terminator") end),
```

This would bind keys <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open terminator. <kbd>modkey</kbd> is a variable set in rc.lua, then it doesn't need (can't) to be escaped. It defaults for <kbd>Super</kbd>key.

You can also put your keybindings at the end of globalkeys (after all the default keybindings), but if you do, make sure you avoid the ending comma `,` in the last keybinding, and add a closing comma to the last binding just before the last one, example:

```
-- {{{ Key bindings
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(
   -- LOTS of stuff after:
     awful.key({ modkey }, "x",
               function ()
                   awful.prompt.run({ prompt = "Run Lua code: " },
                   mypromptbox[mouse.screen].widget,
                   awful.util.eval, nil,
                   awful.util.getdir("cache") .. "/history_eval")
               end),
     -- My Bindings
     awful.key({ }, "F1", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("terminator") end)
)
```

Pay attention to the last binding (the one that I created for F1); it has no ending comma, and the one before the last has a comma.

Then you can reload the configuration (default keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>) and see if the new configuration is working. When the user configuration `rc.lua` fails, Awesome loads the main one from the system. Otherwise, you can check the configuration file via terminal, with `awesome -k`.

Sorry if this was confusing. If anything is unclear just tell me and I can try to improve.

Answer (score 16):

You can add keyboard shortcuts by editing `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`.

open `rc.lua` in your favorite editor:

```
vim ~/.config/awesome/rc.lua
```

and to run `firefox` with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> add the following  line:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift" }, "w", function () awful.util.spawn("firefox") end)
```

`modkey` is usually <kbd>Super</kbd> key that can be changed in `rc.lua`. Replace "firefox" with whatever program or command you want to run. Before defining your own keybindings checkout for predefined keybindings in `rc.lua` to avoid conflicts.

Another example: `dmrun` with <kbd>Supre</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>:

```
awful.key({ modkey, }, "r", function () awful.util.spawn("dmrun") end)
```

After making changes to `rc.lua` its important to check configuration file for errors by running the following command:

```
awesome -k
```

You should see something like this:

```
✔ Configuration file syntax OK
```