# Awesome WM - How do you set a hotkey to lock your system?

Tags: window-manager, awesome

When using Awesome Window Manager, how do you set a hotkey to lock your system?

I'd preferably like to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> so that I can lock my screen when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Arch Linux [How to lock screen with awesome window manager [SOLVED]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=82746):

> I will also recommend `xscreensaver`, simply because it has ways of
>   letting you know when the screen is locked (it comes with a ton of
>   screensavers to chose from). To lock using `xscrensaver`, do this:
>
> 1. Install xscreensaver (Ed: `sudo apt install xscreensaver`)
> 2. Add `xscreensaver -no-splash &` to your `$HOME/.xinitrc` (Ed: This file doesn't exist in Ubuntu Unity 16.04. In **Startup Applications** you add the command `xscreensaver -nosplash`)
> 3. Make a keybinding in Awesome that spawns `xscreensaver-command -lock`. This will start the screensaver and ask for a password.
>
> Suckless' `slock` is rather small, but all it does is blank the screen
>   and wait for input. Input is not even echoed, you don't see anything,
>   so you might as well have a locked box and not know it.

<sub>When you see **(Ed: ...)** above, they are comments added by me and are not in Arch Linux answer</sub>

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/279176/how-to-add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-awesome-wm